# Replicate Left join on multiple fields in solr

Tags: mysql, join, solr

I have a mysql query:

```
select t1.to_step,count(t1.to_step) from tmp t1 left join tmp t3 on 
(t1.to_step = t3.from_step and t1.applicant_id=t3.applicant_id)
where t3.to_step is null group by t1.to_step
```

I am trying to do the above in solr using joins. I know joins in solr work like nested query but i am not able to figure out a proper way to get all the records as i get from the mysql query.

below is what i am using:

```
q: "-_query_:\"{!join from=from_step_s to=to_step_s}from_step_s:[* TO *]\"",
```

This gives me partial set of results. Basically my solr document consists of  fields `applicant_id`, `from_step_s` and `to_step_s` and I want to get the document where a join from a `to_step_s` to `from_step_s` doesn't exist for a particular set of `applicant_id`. I think the problem is somewhere because of the `applicant_id`join not done in the solr query (which i dont know how to do) because of which the `from_step_s` of one document gets matched to `to_step_s` of a different document with different `applicant_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is about a join based on two fields (on each side).

The short answer: You cannot do this.

The main logic for `JoinQuery` is in [org.apache.solr.search.JoinQuery.JoinQueryWeight.getDocSet()](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/3019415/). As you will see there is no use of stored fields or a search which you could change from one field to two fields.

The [Erick Erickson](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2012/06/20/solr-and-joins/) answer:

> You should not do this.

Solr lives from de-normalization. Why not add a new field and concat the old ones? Why not use your sql join at indexing time and add the information you need directly to the index?

Comment: But is there a way I can iterate over the result set of a parent query from inside a subquery or something like that to iterate over resultset ?

Comment: I am trying to implement statistics .. thats why the requirement..if i precalculate and store the stats it would require very frequent updates..

Comment: If time does not matter: You can build your own QueryComponent or QParser and work directly on lucene index. If all your "applicant_id" with all corresponding DocSets can be cached in main memory you even could think about your own version of JoinQuery.